# Interval of Initial Value Problems

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem states:

$y= 1 / (x^2 + C)$ is a solution to $y' + 2xy^2 = 0$

if $y(2) = 1/3$, find $C$:

Simply enough, $C = -1$.

But now it says, *Give the largest interval I over which the solution is defined*.

for the solution to be defined,  $x$ cannot equal $\pm 1$, and therefore the interval of
solution would be:

$(-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$

but the book only says that the interval is $(1,+\infty)$

is it wrong to mention the other two intervals in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the interval that contains the $x$ value at which the initial condition was prescribed. Since you were given $y(2)=1/3$, you want the largest interval containing $x=2$, i.e., $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $(-\infty,−1)\cup (−1,1) \cup (1,\infty)$ is NOT an interval. An interval always contains all numbers that lie between two of its elements.